# ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails when upgrading from mysql 5.5 to 5.7

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am experiencing an error when trying to run a data import on mysql 5.7 that is currently working on mysql 5.5.

The full error is as follows :

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`media24`.`action_item_group`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FKAC29F3FCFCAFE3B0` FOREIGN KEY (`updated_by_employee_id`) REFERENCES
>   `employee` (`id`))

Basic overview of problematic table

```
 | | created_by_employee_id     | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |  
 | | updated_by_employee_id     | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |
 | | exit_reason_id             | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |
 | | root_action_item_group_id  | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |
 | | forwarding_contact_no      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |
 | | forwarding_email           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |
 | | tenant_id                  | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | 0       |
 | | employee_job_position_id   | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |
```

Comment: Please learn to format you question properly after 30 posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn this off by adding this before the insert command :

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
```

then set it back after your inserts:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Just beware and make sure you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

According to your problem one of these 3 solutions may help you:

1- You are importing a table(Name it A) which has FK to some fields in other table(Name it B).
As you did not have table B in your new database, whenever you wanna import table A, it shows you error on setting that FK.

2- Also check if you are trying to add a row to your table for which no matching row (`id`) is present in `employee` table

3- Don't forget to check for duplicate values either